# Not sure how tho get my bot to watch one channel

Tags: python, bots, discord

so im trying to build a bot that only allows one word to be said in a certain channel, ive gotten the first bit setup but im not sure how to get it to just watch the one specific channel

this is what ive got so far, not even sure if it will work tho...

```html
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('mytoken')

client = discord.client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.content != "e") return message.delete()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `on_message` event and check if the channel is the one you're looking for and if the message contains the word. For each message check if `message.channel.id` is equal to the specific channel's id:

```
 special_id = #the channel id you get by right clicking on a channel and click copy ID
 special_word = 'your_word'
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.channel.id == special_id:
            if not special_word in message.content:
                await message.channel.purge(1)#delete the message the user sent
                await message.channel.send('you must have "{}" in your message in this channel'.format(special_word)
```